# How to build this Chart (gantt)?

Tags: pgfgantt, charts, flow-charts

Can you help me? In the following picture I have chart, which I want to build with LaTeX, but I don't know if or how it's possible.

[image: Is this possible?]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[left=30mm,right=40mm,top=25mm,bottom=20mm, includeheadfoot]{geometry}% centering hinter headfoot

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[rm={tabular, lining},sf={tabular, lining},tt={monowidth, tabular, lining}]{cfr-lm}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}

 \begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
  {\sffamily
   \begin{ganttchart}

   \end{ganttchart}
  }
 \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I have absolutely no idea how to start. Can someone help me? Is it possible to build it like that even with those colors?

Comment: There are a lot of [examples](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=gantt), you could start to investigate.  I am sure, that this could be done.

Comment: @Jan they are all not like that what i want i dont know how to start this ...